# Are Verb 1 and Verb 2 interchangeable? verb1+te verb2 vs. verb2+te verb1

Tags: verbs, て-form

For example, is there a difference between these two sentences?

- 風は夜になっておさまった。
- 風は夜に治まってなった。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "No".

The te-form has various functions, and in this example, it expresses Verb 2 happens after Verb 1 happens. Swapping them will change the essential meaning of the sentence.

1. 風は夜になっておさまった。
   The wind, after night fell, ceased.
2. 夜になって風はおさまった。
   Night fell and (then) the wind ceased.
3. 風はおさまって夜になった。
   The wind ceased and (then) night fell.
4. ❌ 風は夜に治まってなった。
   ❌ The wind, night, ceased and (then) fell.

Here, Sentences 1 and 2 share the same meaning because the verb order is preserved. However, Sentences 2 and 3 have different meanings. Besides, in your example, 風 corresponds to おさまる, and 夜 corresponds to なる. You cannot construct a sentence like Sentence 4, in which a modifier and the modified word do not have a clean *nested* relationship.

Sometimes the te-form can simply join two verbs in a way the order is not important. For example, 食べて飲む "to eat and drink" and 飲んで食べる "to drink and eat" are usually interchangeable because which to do first is normally unimportant. Such cases are not very common, though.